# Scrollify scrolling to bottom of footer?

Tags: jquery-scrollify

When using scrollify and setting the footer as an interstitialSection with a class if the footer is taller than the viewport height it scrolls to the bottom of the footer not the top so you don't see where the footer begins? I would like it to snap to the top of the footer so then you can continue scrolling down to see whats in the footer?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(function() {
            $.scrollify({
            section: ".section",
            sectionName : "section-name",
            interstitialSection : ".footer-end",
            scrollSpeed: 1500

            });
        });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to not set your footer as an `interstitialSection`. It should be a regular section.

Comment: the script is great but everything we need/ask is an "addon" and browsing stack for "possible" tweaks is not what is expected. $.scrollify.move  to footer that is  interstitialSection does not work either, the footer or header are excluded so if you have menu with link to it, it wont work http://i.prntscr.com/NmbXsXNaSsO7mZgLsqMCvQ.png